# Jquery images shown like collage/gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I need collage or gallery jquery/JS plugin, which would put images like this and when image is clicked it will become larger, but without any white spaces. 
Here is JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxr5w4dd/2/

CSS:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: black;
color: white;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:5px;
float:left;
vertical-align:top;
```

JS:

```
$('.item').click(function(e) {
        if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
            $(this).animate({height:'100px', width:'100px'},300).removeClass('selected');
        else
            $(this).animate({height:'205px', width:'205px'},300).addClass('selected');
    });
```

The problem with this one is that when you click on last row element, there is white space, and I would like to fill those white spaces.

I had found collagePlus plugins and others, but I just didn't find a way to implement them.

Just Question maybe you had such problem and you have some ideas how to achieve similar result?

Comment: Did you used your favorite search engine? ;) Here for instance are some jQuery Galleries http://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/

Answer (score 0):

Might want to check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).  I'm not sure if it will do exactly what you want but I know it's similar.